# Mysql -h option not working

Tags: mysql

I am trying to connect mysql hosted onto a remote machine and everytime I provide the remote host with -h option it's still taking local machines hostname

example

```
mysql -u user-p pass -h "IP" -P 3306 -D DB
Enter password:
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'user'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

Not sure why it's ignoring the remote host name. It's showing localhost's hostname instead of the IP I am providing

Comment: Have you tried without the quotes around the hostname? Or with the long version of the argument --host=IP?

Comment: @davidrv87 Why would removing the quotes make a difference? You know that quotes are processed by the shell, the program never sees them.

Comment: Very true @Barmar, my bad! Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

You can't put a space between `-p` and the password.

```
mysql -u user -ppass -h IP -P 3306 -D DB
```

If there's nothing immediately after `-p`, it prompts for the password instead of getting it from the command line.

This error is causing the rest of the command line to be parsed incorrectly. It thinks `-p` is the last option, because the next word doesn't begin with `-`.